# Double width website

Tags: html, css, web2py

I can't figure out why our website has such a large width. Here's a link to it: `https://85.25.242.165/lunatic/default/index`

As you can see there is a scroll bar at the bottom and the whole width is roughly double the size of the website. I've tried finding an item that is so wide via Firebug but no luck. Everything is within the original width of the website.

We're using the Web2py framework.

Comment: Please do not ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Please post the relevant code as part of your question.

Comment: Did you try removing elements until the scroll bar went away?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know it was a big deal, as I said down there, I'm still new to this. Won't happen again!

Comment: I'm getting the "not trusted site"-page in Chrome.

Comment: Actually it's the certificate that is non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's your problem

```
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -99.5%;
}
```

add

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Eric! I've worked on it all this time without noticing the bottom scroll bar. Yes, I'm still learning this stuff. Thanks once again! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which occured in Firefox Mac only, when I added this code:

```
body {
  transform: translateZ(0); // This enables hardware acceleration for smoother animations. 
}
```

As the comment says, it is supposed to smooth animations but it ended up ruining my site on FFv24 Mac.